How do I download CSV file from investing.com
I would like to download the CSV file from this link:
https://it.investing.com/rates-bonds/it0005583486-historical-data.
I used Selenium with Excel, and I managed to enter the user and password, but once I arrived at the Download (CSV) button, I got stuck. Where am I wrong? Below is the HTML code and my macro.
  With dD
        '.Start
        .Get Url
        ' clicca "accetta"
        dD.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='onetrust-button-group-parent']").Click
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

        '----------------------------------------  Login ---------------------------------------

        ' accedi

        Set Btn = dD.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/header/div[1]/section/div[3]/ul/li[1]/button/span")
        Btn.Click

        ' accedi tramite mail
        Set btn1 = dD.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/form/button[4]/span")
        btn1.Click

        ' inserisce user
        .FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=':rb:']/form/div[3]/input").SendKeys myUser

        'inserisce password
        .FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=':rb:']/form/div[5]/input").SendKeys myPassword

        ' conferma pulsante accedi

        Set btn2 = dD.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=':rb:']/form/button/span")
        btn2.Click
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
        
        ' pulsante accedi
        Set btn3 = dD.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/form/button")
        btn3.Click
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))

    '--------------------------------------------- here the error

       '//*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/span[2]
        Set btn4 = dD.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='__next']/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/span[2]")
       btn4.Click

       ' Set btn4 = dD.FindElementByCss("span.text-center:nth-child(2)")
        ' btn4.Click
        
 '------------------------------------------------------------
                   fName = myIsin & ".csv"
                   mioFile = Percorso & fName
                  .SaveAs Filename:=mioFile, Local:=False, CreateBackup:=False

    End With
    dD.Quit
    Call ConvertiCSV

    Set dD = Nothing
    Set wks = Nothing
    Set Wks1 = Nothing
End Sub

enter image description here
I want to download csv file.

You can try my below code which does not use Selenium so, it is much more reliable.
You can change the start and end dates in the URL or, you can get the dates from  2 cells on the sheet.
Here is the code (written and tested on Excel 2010 - 64 Bit);
Sub GetData()
    Dim URL As String, objXMLHTTP As Object, strCOOKIE As String
    Dim strJSON As String, regExp As Object, arrPattern(1 To 7) As Variant, xPattern As Variant
    Dim r As Integer, c As Integer, RetVal As Object, objList As ListObject
    
    Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    
    URL = "https://api.investing.com/api/financialdata/historical/1212094?start-date=2024-11-14&end-date=2024-12-14&time-frame=Daily&add-missing-rows=false"
    
    With objXMLHTTP
      .Open "GET", URL, False
      .setRequestHeader "Domain-Id", "it"
      .send
    End With
        
    If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
        Range("A1:G" & Rows.Count) = ""
        Range("A1:G1") = Array("Date", "Last Close", "Last Open", "Last Max", "Last Min", "Volume", "Change (%)")
    
        strJSON = objXMLHTTP.responseText
            
        arrPattern(1) = """rowDate"":""(.+?)"","
        arrPattern(2) = """last_close"":""(.+?)"","
        arrPattern(3) = """last_open"":""(.+?)"","
        arrPattern(4) = """last_max"":""(.+?)"","
        arrPattern(5) = """last_min"":""(.+?)"","
        arrPattern(6) = """volume"":""(.+?)"","
        arrPattern(7) = """change_precent"":""(.+?)"","
        
        Set regExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    
        regExp.ignorecase = True
        regExp.Global = True
    
        For Each xPattern In arrPattern
            regExp.Pattern = xPattern
            r = 1
            c = c + 1
            If regExp.Test(strJSON) Then
                For Each RetVal In regExp.Execute(strJSON)
                    r = r + 1
                    Cells(r, c) = RetVal.Submatches(0)
                Next
            End If
        Next
        
        Set objList = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        
        With objList
            .Name = "List_Investing"
            .Range.Columns.AutoFit
        End With
        
        MsgBox "Done...!", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "URL problem...."
    End If
    
    Set regExp = Nothing
    Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
End Sub

Output on the sheet:
.


Hi, your file is "perfetto" and works very well. Thanks very much.

Just one question: where can I find the title code (1212094) corresponding to the isin it0005583486? Thank you

You can get the api URL by inspecting the network traffic of your original URL
